# Gatling - requirement failed: No scenario set up

Tags: gatling

Im fairly new into programming, i was trying to launch my test but i got : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No scenario set up
even if i got the scenario set up (which is confusing)
i'm pretty sure is something obvious that newbie like me can't figure out unfortunately.
i tried invalidating caches, and reloading the project.
im using intelij + maven

```scala
package simulations

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.structure.{ChainBuilder, ScenarioBuilder}
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.protocol.HttpProtocolBuilder

class GatlingDemoStore extends Simulation {

  val domain = "demostore.gatling.io"

  val httpProtocol: HttpProtocolBuilder = http
    .baseUrl("http://" + domain)


  object login {
    def userlogin: ChainBuilder = {
      exec(http("Login User")
        .post("/login")
        .formParam("_csrf", "${csrfValue}")
        .formParam("username", "user1")
        .formParam("password", "pass"))
    }
  }

  object CmsPages {
    def homepage: ChainBuilder = {
      exec(http("Load Home Page")
        .get("/")
        .check(status.is(200))
        .check(regex("<title>Gatling Demo-Store</title>").exists)
        .check(css("#_csrf", "content").saveAs("csrfValue")))
    }

    def aboutus: ChainBuilder = {
      exec(http("Load Home Page")
        .get("/about-us")
        .check(status.is(200))
        .check(substring("About Us")))
    }

    def categories: ChainBuilder = {
      exec(http("Load Categories Page")
        .get("/category/all")
        .check(status.is(200)))
        .pause(10)
    }

    def productpage: ChainBuilder = {
      exec(http("Load Product Page")
        .get("/product/black-and-red-glasses")
        .check(status.is(200)))
        .pause(15)
    }

    def addtocart: ChainBuilder = {
      exec(http("Add Product to Cart")
        .get("/cart/add/19"))
    }

    def viewcart: ChainBuilder = {
      exec(http("View Cart")
        .get("/cart/view"))
    }

    def checkout: ChainBuilder = {
      exec(http("Checkout")
        .get("/cart/checkout"))
    }

    val User: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("DemoStore Simulation")
      .exec(CmsPages.homepage)
      .pause(5)
      .exec(CmsPages.aboutus)
      .pause(5)
      .exec(CmsPages.categories)
      .pause(20)
      .exec(CmsPages.productpage)
      .pause(5)
      .exec(CmsPages.addtocart)
      .pause(2)
      .exec(login.userlogin)


    setUp(
      User.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
    ).protocols(httpProtocol)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reformatted your code so your error is more obvious: you're calling `setUp` not in the body of the `GatlingDemoStore` class but in the body of the  `CmsPages` object, which is never loaded (in Scala, objects are lazily loaded and here you never call it).

Move `setUp` in the body of the `GatlingDemoStore` class.

**Important note: as you're new to programming, you should probably go with Java (supported since Gatling 3.7) instead of Scala.**

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your help, greatly appreciated.
seems like a rookie mistake..
thats a great idea actually, ima do some research on  how i can do that.

Comment: Add appriciations as comments not the answers.